# Salesforce Community Migration : The label must be unique. Remove duplicates in routes/sfdcPage.json and try again

Tags: community, deployment, package, migration, package.xml

I am trying to migrate community from one salesforce environment to another. I am not able to migrate since I am getting the below error during the migration of the ExperienceBundle.

**The error message says "The label must be unique. Remove duplicates in routes/sfdcPage.json and try again." .**

I don't have any route file named "sfdcPage.json" inside the experience builder when I was trying to deploy.

I have faced this earlier for the theme folder inside the experience builder. I have resolved it by changing the name of the theme and it worked. But I am not sure how to resolve the error related to sfdcPage.json route file since I am not able to find any file named "sfdcPage.json" as such.

Comment: Hey Kamal, did you resolve the issue with `duplicates in routes/sfdcPage.json`? I am experiencing the same issue. Interesting thing is I got this error when I tried to deploy the ExperienceBundle second time. On the first attempt it deployed successfully.

Comment: @Eduard I have not resolved the issue still. Looking for a solution :( It was also happened for me on subsequent migration as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems related to this KI https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JiQrQAK for which fix is planned to be shipped with next patch.